# Sort numbers using easy68k

Tags: assembly, 68000

How can I sort number in descending order by using easy68k? Please give some suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still learning 68k asm, but obviously you could accomplish this task with the `cmp` opcode.

Here's a quicksort implementation I found [at this site](http://pat.dmj.free.fr/us/programes.htm):

```
************************************************************SIM68K V1.1US***
*                                                                          *
*   Program : QSORT.ASM                                                    *
*   Quick Sort is a classical recursive sort algorithm.                    *
*   Being very famous, I prefer you search how it works in a computer      *
*   science book.                                                          *
*    This instance of "Quick Sort" algorithm sorts an unsigned byte table  *
*    ($FF = 255) by ascending value.                                       *
*                                                                          *
*    Stack top contains min and max indexes of the sub-table being sorted  *
*                                                                          *
* SIM68K.INI options should be :                                           *
* - BIOS = 0 or 1                                                          *
* - VAL_RAM=RANDOM                                                         *
* - RAM_AD=$2000 to see table                                              *
*                                                                          *
******************************************(C)1994-1998*Patrick DEMIRDJIAN***

*       min and max indexes of main table to be sorted
min     equ     0
*       $3F = MEMORY window size
max     equ     $3f

* Program start address
        org     $1000

* Stack pointer init, IT masking and full speed mode setting
        lea     $7ffe,a7
        ori.w   #$700,sr
        andi.w  #$7fff,sr

* A0 holds start address of table
        lea     $2000,a0

* D0 holds min index
        move.l  #min,d0

* D1 holds max index
        move.l  #max,d1

* Q_SORT subroutine call
        bsr     q_sort

* End of program by pseudo monitor call
        trap    #0

*****************************************************************************
Q_SORT  equ     *          
*       Save min and max indexes in the stack
        move.w  d0,-(a7)
        move.w  d1,-(a7)
*       D2 = "middle" index = D0 + ((D1 - D0) / 2) = "pivot" index
* Why is this formula better than (D1+D0)/2 ?

        move.w  d1,d2
        sub.w   d0,d2
        lsr.w   #1,d2
        add.w   d0,d2

*       D3 = table "pivot" element
        move.b  0(a0,d2.w),d3

*       Search for table 1st element > pivot, starting from table top
next1   equ     *
        cmp.b   0(a0,d0.w),d3
        bls     next2
        addq.w  #1,d0
        bra     next1

*       Search for table 1st element < pivot, starting from table bottom
next2   equ     *        
        move.b  0(a0,d1.w),d4
        cmp.b   d3,d4
        bls     swap
        subq.w  #1,d1
        bra     next2

swap    equ     *
        cmp.w   d1,d0
        bgt     suite

*       Swap elements through D5        
        move.b  0(a0,d0.w),d5
        move.b  0(a0,d1.w),0(a0,d0.w)
        move.b  d5,0(a0,d1.w)

*       Refresh indexes
        addq.w  #1,d0
        subq.w  #1,d1

        cmp.w   d1,d0
        bgt     suite
        bra     next1

suite   equ     *
        cmp.w   2(a7),d1
        ble     next3

*       Save current registers in stack       
        move.w  2(a7),d6
        move.w  d0,-(a7)
        move.w  d1,-(a7)
        move.w  d6,d0

*       Recursive call with new indexes
*       Sort sub-table
        bsr     q_sort

*       Get current registers from stack
        move.w  (a7)+,d1
        move.w  (a7)+,d0

next3   equ     *
        cmp.w   (a7),d0
        bge     fin

*       Save current registers in stack       
        move.w  (a7),d6
        move.w  d0,-(a7)
        move.w  d1,-(a7)
        move.w  d6,d1

*       Recursive call with new indexes
*       Sort sub-table
        bsr     q_sort

*       Get current registers from stack
        move.w  (a7)+,d1
        move.w  (a7)+,d0

fin     equ     *        
*       Remove indexes from stack
        adda.l  #4,a7

        rts

* Suggestion_1
* Modify tests to sort signed bytes table ($FF = -1).
* Display in D7 stack max size.

* Suggestion_2
* Modify Q_SORT to sort word and long word tables.
```